# Order of steps to display a picture behind text on LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice

I was glad to find out how to get my picture behind the text by clicking on Arrange and then Send to Back / Send Backwards, but still my picture either obscured the text or pushed it down.

Question: do I type text first (in this case in a frame / text box, and then add the picture, or is there another way? Also, must my text be in or out the frame to start of with?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are partly right, from the format menu choose WRAP:
[image: Write format tab]

Now you can choose how to blend text and picture, such as text through the picture, or in background.
Try them out to find the effect that pleases you!

This menu is also reachable by right clicking on your picture in the Libreoffice programs :-)

Happy Ubunting.